# randomization test on differences

Tags: anova, nested-data, ecology, permutation-test

I have three treatments (A, B, and C) that I would like to compare. However, within each treatment, I have nested "high" and "low" (H and L) treatments. The values for A, B, and C must be calculated as the difference between H and L treatments.

There is no intentional pairing of samples between the H and L treatments of each A, B, and C treatment. Hence, I need to bootstrap the difference between H and L for each treatment, and then compare the means of this outcome.

What is the most appropriate way of doing this to test a hypothesis concerning the difference in treatment groups A, B, and C?

If anyone is curious, this is a light-bottle, dark-bottle study for an ecology experiment.

Comment: I suppose my reputations is not enough to edit tags, but I think "nested" tag is not appropriate here and "anova" tag would fit better the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question you can control three variables in your experiment (treatments A, B, C) and for each treatment you have two levels (H and L).

You seem to be facing a quite standard problem of design of experiments and  if you run one or several experiments with every combination of high and low levels of every treatment (e.g., LLL, LLH, LHL, LHH and so) you have a [2^3 factorial design](http://www.stat.washington.edu/pds/stat502/LectureNotes/2k.factorial.intro.pdf). Your data can be analysed with [ANOVA (analysis of variance)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance). In short, ANOVA is a set of tests of hypothesis about whether every treatment affects the response.

What is not advised to do is to perform t-tests to compare means separately for each treatment, that I'm afraid is what you mean by "bootstrap the difference between H and L for each treatment, and then compare the means of this outcome". ANOVA does this comparison for all treatments at the same time, takes in account interactions between different treatments, and avoids some problems that arise when doing multiple comparisons.

And just to add a side note: beware that if every treatment has two levels (high and low), levels are not "nested" in the treatment. In this context "nested" has a very different meaning (one treatment could be nested in another).

Comment: Thanks Pere! However, the solution is not as simple as you suggest. Indeed, I have a 3x2 factorial design. within each of the 6 resulting treatments, I have 10 replicates. Now, here is where the problem becomes complicated. 5 of the 10 replicates are "light" and 5 of the 10 replicates are "dark." You might be tempted to say I have a 3x2x2 factorial design, except I want the mean of each treatment to be a latent variable resulting from the addition of the light and dark replicates.

Comment: One easy way out could be to randomly select a single high and a single low replicate, add them together, repeat this four more times, and voila...I have my replicates that I can run a standard ANOVA on. However, this is not appropriate because there is no a priori pairing of replicates. I came up with an alternative solution. Simply calculate the sum of all possible combinations of "light" and "dark" replicates (for 5 of each, this would be 25 combinations), and bootstrap the heck out of it. Gets me a mean and confidence interval.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't not follow you. If I understand your comment, "light" and "dark" are two levels of another factor, not just two levels of the previous treatments. Then you do have a 3x2x2 factorial design, and when computing effects for each factor (and its significance), the effects of other factors are averaged by ANOVA. In fact, ANOVA for fixed effects is not very different from a t-test for each factor (estimates are the same, confidence intervals and significance are different).